Filter rows in an R tidy data frame based on same-column values that are located in different rows
I am trying to filter out the species (ASV) in samples that have lower abundance counts than the same species in controls. Below is a simplified version of my tidy data table:



ASV
ID
Type
Batch
Counts




ASV1
Control23
Con1
B1
5000


ASV2
Control23
Con1
B1
2000


ASV1
Sample21
S
B1
4000


ASV2
Sample21
S
B1
6000


ASV1
Sample28
S
B1
10000


ASV2
Control25
Con25
B2
25000


ASV3
Control25
Con25
B2
9000


ASV2
Sample12
S
B2
70000


ASV3
Sample12
S
B2
26000


ASV2
Sample10
S
B2
3100



For example, I would want to remove ASV1 in Sample21 from the dataset because its counts are less than the Control23 that was used for Batch B1. Another example: I want to keep ASV2 in Sample12 because its counts are higher than the counts of the same species in Control25 in Batch B2.
I've been using tidyverse to clean and group my data but I'm stuck as to how to subset the ASV count value for the control in each batch. I thought it would be simple to use filter as follows:
df_ASV.Tidy.Batch <- df_ASV.Tidy %>% 
   group_by(Batch, Type, ID, ASV) %>% 
   filter((Type != "S" & Counts > 0) > (Type != "C" & Counts > 0)) 

But the output only acknowledged the argument for Type != "S" & Counts > 0 and not Type != "C" & Counts > 0, and the output was the same even without Type != "C" & Counts > 0.
I think I would likely need to create a new column by mutate or summarise to return TRUE or FALSE and then use filter, but it returns back to the original problem where I can't figure out how to specifically compare the count values of control vs sample of the same species and batch.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can indentify the ones to remove using a non-equi join, and then anti-join on those:
anti_join(
  df_ASV.Tidy, 
  inner_join(
    df_ASV.Tidy %>% filter(substr(ID,1,1)=="S"),
    df_ASV.Tidy %>% filter(substr(ID,1,1)=="C"),
    join_by(ASV, Batch, x$Counts<y$Counts)
  ) %>% distinct(ASV, Batch, ID =ID.x)
)

Output:
   ASV        ID  Type Batch Counts
1 ASV1 Control23  Con1    B1   5000
2 ASV2 Control23  Con1    B1   2000
3 ASV2  Sample21     S    B1   6000
4 ASV1  Sample28     S    B1  10000
5 ASV2 Control25 Con25    B2  25000
6 ASV3 Control25 Con25    B2   9000
7 ASV2  Sample12     S    B2  70000
8 ASV3  Sample12     S    B2  26000

This removes the following:

ASV1, Sample21 (because less than Control 23 in the same batch/species
ASV2, Sample10 (because less than Control 25 in the same batch/species

An alternative approach is to identify the samples you want to retain using the non-equi join, and then row bind with the controls
bind_rows(
  inner_join(
    df_ASV.Tidy %>% filter(substr(ID,1,1)=="S"),
    df_ASV.Tidy %>% filter(substr(ID,1,1)=="C"),
    join_by(ASV, Batch, x$Counts>y$Counts)
  ) %>% select(ASV, ID=ID.x, Type=Type.x, Batch, Counts = Counts.x),
  df_ASV.Tidy %>% filter(substr(ID,1,1) == "C")
)

Result is equivalent.

If you have one Control per group ASV/Batch using your filter approach
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(grepl("^Con", Type) | 
           Counts[grepl("^Con", Type)] < Counts, .by = c(Batch, ASV))
   ASV        ID  Type Batch Counts
1 ASV1 Control23  Con1    B1   5000
2 ASV2 Control23  Con1    B1   2000
3 ASV2  Sample21     S    B1   6000
4 ASV1  Sample28     S    B1  10000
5 ASV2 Control25 Con25    B2  25000
6 ASV3 Control25 Con25    B2   9000
7 ASV2  Sample12     S    B2  70000
8 ASV3  Sample12     S    B2  26000

Note that if you also group by ID, the Samples never see the Control.
